# Convert Python 2 into Python 3 (with Python 2 style execution)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a code in Python 2 which I would like to convert to Python 3, however the behaviour of the code MUST remain exactly the same as on Python 2 interpreter.

**Especially division must behave like on Python 2 interpreter.**

I tried with `futurize` stage 1 and 2 but division remains just `/` on the code, which generates errors on execution because returned number is of type `float` instead of type `int` (which was a default behaviour for code executed on Python 2 interpreter).

**EDIT:** `3 // 2 = 1.0` which is `float` in Python 3. Is there a way to return `int`?

Answer (score 1):

Futurize/Modernize/2to3 can't statically analyze which divisions are integer division.

You will need to manually go through division operations in the converted code and figure out which should use `//` for integer division and which should use `/` for real division.

Naturally, your code base's test cases should find any regressions here. ;)

Comment: But if all Python 2 divisions with `/` are type `int` - there should be a `futurize` flag to change  all those `/` into `//`. At least on your own risk.

Comment: Then you should be able to just search-and-replace for ` / ` -> ` // ` (taking care not to change anything that might be in string literals or similar of course).

Comment: that's why I'm asking - to not convert strings with simple replace. I have 100+`/` matches in 11 files and I'm sure I want to change all `/` div to `//`.

Comment: Well, if it helps, PyCharm's search-and-replace feature has a filter for "Except Comments and String Literals" :)

Comment: well, that's may be helpful, but I can't believe there is no way to do this (on your own risk) by Futurize/Modernize/2to3.

Comment: Well, you _can_ look at e.g. https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future/blob/c423752879acc05eebc29b0bb9909327bd5c7308/src/libfuturize/fixes/fix_division_safe.py and make it emit `//` for all divisions it encounters. :)

Answer (score 0):

The integer division operator is `//` in python 3.

```
>>> 3 / 2
1.5
>>> 3 // 2
1
```

edit:
The only way I know of to get compatible behavior from both versions of python is to futurize the python 2 `/` operation and to convert any instances that expect integer division in the python 2 program to instead use `//` which works for integer divisions in both python 2 and 3.

Comment: thanks ;) But how can I forced `futurize` to change all those divisions? Because if I simply replace `/` with `//` it can generate other errors

Comment: if you want code compatible with both python 2 and 3 i'd use the python 3 operation for `/` instead. You can futurize the division in the python 2 program and update the instances where you need integer division to use `//` which also does integer division in python 2

Comment: `3 // 2 = 1.0` which is `float`. Is there a way to return `int`?

Comment: @Ziemo: `3 // 2` => `1` in Python 3 (result type `int`)